# Drawing system architecture in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, metapost

I want to draw a system architecture as in the picture below
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Easiest way: Use `Inkscape` and export to TikZ-code.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: You can't expect the results of this conversion to be easy to work with - if you want to work with Inkscape, save the processor cycles and export as PDF.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe something along these lines with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,fit,scopes}
\tikzset{
  >= latex,
  el/.style={ellipse, draw, text width=8em, align=center},
  rs/.style={rectangle split, draw, rectangle split parts=#1},
  ou/.style={draw, inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1ex, fit=#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[matrix of nodes, row sep=5ex, column sep=1em] (mx) {
    INPUT:& |[el]| newspaper text \\
    ANALYSER& |[rs=3]|
    lexical tagger\nodepart{two}morphological analyser\nodepart{three}parser \\
    & |[el]| {analysed newspaper text} \\
    SIMPLIFIER& |[rs=2]| syntactic simplifier\nodepart{two}lexical simplifier \\
    OUTPUT:& |[el]| simplified newspaper text \\
  };
  \node[ou=(mx-2-2)] (ana) {};
  \node[ou=(mx-4-2)] (sim) {};
  {[->]
  \draw(mx-1-2)edge(ana) (ana)edge(mx-3-2) (mx-3-2)edge(sim) (sim)edge(mx-5-2);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with MetaPost (compile with `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
input boxes;

nodesep := 15; % space between nodes
ellipdy := 15; % the dy of ellipses

vardef cuta(suffix a, b) = % from Peter Grogono's MetaPost reference manual
  drawarrow a.c -- b.c cutbefore bpath.a cutafter bpath.b;
enddef;

beginfig(1);
  % define contents
  circleit.txt("newspaper text");
  boxjoin(a.sw = b.nw; a.se = b.ne);
  boxit.lext("lexical tagger");
  boxit.mora("morphological analyser");
  boxit.prsr("parser");
  boxjoin();
  circleit.atxt("analysed text");
  boxjoin(a.sw = b.nw; a.se = b.ne);
  boxit.syns("syntactic simplifier");
  boxit.lexs("lexical simplifier");
  boxjoin();
  circleit.stxt("simplified text");

  % position and tweak
  txt.dy  = ellipdy;
  atxt.dy = ellipdy;
  stxt.dy = ellipdy;
  lext.ne - lext.nw = (110,0);
  txt.s  - lext.n = (0,nodesep);
  prsr.s - atxt.n = (0,nodesep);
  atxt.s - syns.n = (0,nodesep);
  lexs.s - stxt.n = (0,nodesep);

  % draw everything
  picture pic; pic := image(drawboxed(lext, mora, prsr););
  draw pic; draw bbox pic;
  drawboxed(txt, atxt);
  pic := image(drawboxed(syns, lexs));
  draw pic; draw bbox pic;
  drawboxed(stxt);
  cuta(txt, lext);
  cuta(prsr, atxt);
  cuta(atxt, syns);
  cuta(lexs, stxt);
endfig;
end;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, right: a matrix of nodes is itself a node.  Had forgotten about that convenience!

Comment: @Justlife Please consider accepting some of the answers you have received. In several cases, you've indicated in comments that an answer solved your problem nicely, but you have never accepted any of those answers by clicking on the greyed-out checkmark at the top left of the answer. Obviously, you shouldn't accept answers which don't answer your question and it can be good to wait to see several possible solutions, but after that, it would be appreciated if you would consider accepting the answers which have really helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Run with `pdflatex -shell-escape`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}

\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=5mm]
    INPUT:    & \psovalbox{newspaper text} \\
    ANALYSER  & \psframebox{\tabular{|c|}\hline lexical tagger\\\hline
                morphological analyser\\\hline parser\\\hline\endtabular}\\
              & \psovalbox{\parbox{2.5cm}{analysed newspaper text}} \\
    SIMPLIFIER& \psframebox{\tabular{|c|}\hline syntactic simplifier\\\hline
                 lexical simplifier\\\hline \endtabular}\\
    OUTPUT:   & \psovalbox{\parbox{2.5cm}{simplified newspaper text}}
\ncline{->}{1,2}{2,2}\ncline{->}{2,2}{3,2}            
\ncline{->}{3,2}{4,2}\ncline{->}{4,2}{5,2}            
\end{psmatrix}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example output]

Answer (score 3):

TikZ is the best choice, lots of examples you can build on like this one:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/assignment-structure/